# How to send object in params without object name - HttpClientModule

Tags: angular

I know that with new HttpClientModule I should set headers and params in new way:

```
const headers = this.auth.getHeaders(); // here i get headers from another service  
const params = new HttpParams()  
  .set('paramName', JSON.stringify(paramIWantToSend));  
return this.http.put(`${this.API_PATH}/${id}`, {headers, params})
```

Is there a way to send it without a name, just as an object?
not like this:
    {paramName: {ObjectIWantToSend}
but like this:
    {ObjectIWantToSend}

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A JSON object is a set of key/value pairs;the receiving end will not know what it receives without a key.

Comment: @DanielH.J. I cannot edit api, and api want to have just {key: value, key2: value2, (...)}, not {someObjectName: {key: value, key2: value2, (...)}}

Comment: You definitely don't want to do that. For a `PUT` request you really ought to use the body for the payload.

Comment: Chain your params so it's like .set('key1', 'value1').set('key2', 'value2') ...... and the API will get the right result. HttpParams is just a wrapper for your set of key/value pairs.

Comment: @DanielH.J. @ Aluan Haddad you are probably right. Both of you. Ill try it that way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I Understand, you probably need to send the JSON as part of the request body rather than as a parameter, If that is the case, you can send like this,

```
 _httpClient.put(endPoint, paramIWantToSend, headers)
```

[HttpClient Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put)

Comment: yeah i did that, but in a bit different way, since its new httpclient module (like in subject) :)